# How to remove unwanted characters but preserve specific characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Hi I still can't work it out. I'm using preg_replace. I've searched but failed to find a solution. I need to remove unknown characters in the string but preserve new lines.

```
    $summary = "ASDASDASDASDSASD 
    [BS][BS][BS] hello
    this is a new line
[BS][BS][BS] 
this is another new line"; 
    // [BS] is an unknown character if you ever encountered it before in Notepadd++.
    // See screenshot, taken from Notepad++
    // The output in the browser is a series of whitespaces.
    // I can't paste the unknown symbol here. 

    echo preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/','', $summary); 

    // Output: ASDASDASDASDSASD hello this is a new line this is another new line

//Expected Output:
//ASDASDASDASDSASD 
//    hello
//    this is a new line
//this is another new line
```

I'll appreciate all help that i can get.

[image: This is the BS I am talking about]

Comment: Just revise your range to include `\x0A`, `\x0D` (and may the tab character too).

Comment: Hi @SalmanA Can you provide mt the correct regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am looking at http://www.asciitable.com/ and feel like the RegEx should be something like this:

```
/[\x00-\x08\x0B-\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x7F-\xFF]/
```

The range (in fact a blacklist of characters) excludes ASCII tab, new line and carriage return characters which you probably want to keep.

PS: The `BS` is how Notepad++ represents backspace character (ASCII `0x08`).

Comment: Alright, I'll try it. Takes time. My script takes time to load

Answer (score 1):

It's this

```
echo preg_replace('/[\x00-\x09\x0B-\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/','', $summary);
```

Because 0D and 0A (as in \x0D and \x0A being included in \x00-\x1F) are CR+LF. You need to exclude these (and so define multiple Ranges)